# Acrobat Javascript - adding field to top right corner

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm trying to modify this code so that it finds the Crop Box dimensions and just minuses from the top right corner and adds the text field to the top right of the page.  At the moment if there's a page with a landscape orientation, this code places the field off the page as if it was portrait.  I don't mind figuring it out as I like to tinker but if someone could break it down so I can understand what each expression is doing that would be great.  I tried looking it up and found out what some stuff means but in regards to how it's put together I don't quite understand.  I'll use // after the lines I don't quite get.  Thanks in advance.

```
    // Add file name & Page Sequence to footer  
var re = /.*\/|\.pdf$/ig;   //I know what this does but don't understand the breakdown of this. 
var FileNM = this.path.replace(re,""); 
var Path = this.path; 
var AcDate = new Date();   //not sure why this is here, I don't see it used.
var AcDateFormat = "yyyy/mmm/dd  HH:MM"   //not sure why this is here, I don't see it used.
var Box2Width = 50   //not sure why this is here, I don't see it used. 
for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {  
var aRect = this.getPageBox("Crop",p); 
var TotWidth = aRect[2] - aRect[0] 
   var fd = this.addField("xftPage"+p+1, "text", p, [30,1510, 
TotWidth-30-30,40]);       //Not sure what xftPage, text are.  Also don't know why there's 2 -30 
here.
   fd.value =  FileNM + "/" + String(p+1);   //is this the line that actually create the field?
```

```
   fd.textSize=14; fd.readonly = true;
   fd.alignment="right"; 
var bStart=(0);  //not sure what this is
var bEnd=(TotWidth);   //not sure what this is 
} 
this.flattenPages()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes no pages are rotated. You'll need to use this.getPageRoatation(p) where p is the zero-based page number to get the angle of rotation and adjust your coordinates accordingly.